# Access strings file directly without a bundle (from another app)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to access a strings file I use in my iOS app project, from a mac console app I'm writing.

Obviously with my ios app I can access this directly via the bundle...

```
NSString *fname = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"whatever" ofType:@"strings"];
NSDictionary *d = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:fname];
NSString *loc = [d objectForKey:@"LABEL_001"];
```

However, I want to retain the parsing functionality but access the strings file directly.

I haven't been able to find a method to do this?

Comment: Your first code line generates a file name, the second reads and parses the file *without* any dependency on how the file name was produced.  Generate the file name by a different method and your second line will still work, so what exactly is your issue? And what have you tried to solve it?

Comment: Start with the bundle of the iOS app instead of `mainBundle`.

Comment: Thanks @CRD that fixed my issue